# How to keep same background-image ratio/size on all different screen sizes?

Tags: css, background-image

How do you keep the background-image same ratio so that it looks fitted for all different screen-sizes? In other words, how can I make sure the background-image always looks perfectly "centered". Please take note I have several other screens with other background-images so the solution should work for different images, not just the houses below.

CSS :

```
#background{
     background-image: url("../images/houses.png");
     background-color: whitesmoke; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
     height: 100%; /* You must set a specified height */
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
     text-align: center;
     padding: 2.5%;

}
```

This is the desired output for ALL screen sizes. Perfectly aligned :
[image]

However when I resize and experiment with different sizes, the background gets misplaced and does not look really good. It looks like the image is a bit more to the right :

[image]

Comment: use `background-position: center;` for center the image the `#background` element

Comment: `width: 100vw` to make it fit the window width

Comment: @Ramineghbalian: with the rest of the existing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
#background{
  background-image: url("../images/houses.png"); /* The image used */
  background-color: whitesmoke; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  height: 500px; /* You must set a specified height */
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your CSS is telling the page to make sure the background covers the entire screen in both width and height, this will cause some irregularities in screens that don't match your image's aspect ratio. It has to stretch to cover the entire height in your second screen, but "cover" scales in both directions, so it keeps increasing the image size until the whole screen is covered. If you just want to make sure the background fills the screen horizontally (and don't mind that there may be space left at the bottom for taller screens), just set the width to fill the whole screen:

background-size: 100% auto;